# PC file transfer null byte receiving in server side

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, client-server

I have a server code and client that transfer files from client to server in a form of byte[] arrays. But when sending time from client it goes well and no errors in sending code[Client code]. But for the receiving part in Server side it crashes the whole command prompt and stops from running. But the file arrived as well as it sends. But i need to continue the server program to respond after it receives the file. Please help me...Im stucked here...

This is my server code

```
                for(i=0;i<str.length();i++) 
                { 

                    if(str.charAt(i)=='.' || flag==1) 
                    { 
                    flag=1; 
                    extn+=str.charAt(i); 
                    } 
                }                      
                    File file = new File("RecievedImage"+str); 
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file); 

                    //receive and save image from client 
                    byte[] readData = new byte[1024]; 
                    while((i = dis.read(readData)) != -1) 
                    {
                        fout.write(readData, 0, i); 
                        if(flag==1) 
                        { 
                        System.out.println("Image Has Been Received"); 
                        flag=0; 
                        } 
                    } 
                fout.flush(); 
                fout.close();
```

And this is my client code

```
File file = new File(fileName); 
                    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);    
                    dout.writeUTF(fileName); 
                    System.out.println("Sending image..."); 
                    byte[] readData = new byte[1024]; 

                    while((i = fin.read(readData)) != -1) 
                            { 
                            dout.write(readData, 0, i); 
                            } 
                            System.out.println("Image sent"); 
                            ta.appendText("\nImage Has Been Sent"); 
                            fin.close(); 
                    }catch(IOException ex)
                      {System.out.println("Image ::"+ex);}
```

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of `flag`.  This is why you should choose meaningful names for variables, like `extensionFound` (though I’m not at all sure that that is what `flag` means).  What does “crashes” mean?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: ignore the flag variable its useless just using it to receive the name of the file. The server crashing means its not continuing the execution after receiving the file like print or other execution after this code. im not getting any exception it just stops and freeze

Comment: I don’t see any client code which closes `dout`.  If `dout` is never closed, the server will never receive -1 when calling `dis.read`, which means its while loop will never end.

Comment: I closed the dout as u said but it still keep crashing